# Assert.assertEquals on two lists

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I have a class `MySchool`:

```
public class MySchool{
    private long timestamp;
    private SchoolEvent event;
    private Object value;

    //getter & setters
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MySchool [timestamp=" + timestamp + ", event="
                + event + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

`SchoolEvent` is an enum type:

```
public static enum SchoolEvent {
        CEREMONY, HOLIDAY
    }
```

I try to use [Assert.assertEquals()](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to compare two List of schools :

```
List<MySchool> schoolList1 = generateSchools();
List<MySchool> schoolList2 = readSchoolsFromFile();

Assert.assertEquals(schoolList1, schoolList2);
```

It is failed with the following error:

```
expected: java.util.ArrayList<[MySchool [timestamp=0, event=CEREMONY, value=null], MySchool [timestamp=0, event=HOLIDAY, value=null]]> 

but was:  java.util.ArrayList<[MySchool [timestamp=0, event=CEREMONY, value=null], MySchool [timestamp=0, event=HOLIDAY, value=null]]>
```

I don't understand why the error doesn't sound like an error, I mean just check the error message, every field of every element object in two lists are euqal.

I also checked Java doc about [List#equal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) , it also says :

> two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements
>   in the same order.

Why the assertEquals() failed then?

Comment: Your `MySchool` class doesn't override `equals`...

Comment: Why do I need to override `equals` in `MySchool`? Error message shows everything is equal.

Comment: Because by default, `equals` only checks for object identity. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand why the error doesn't sound like an error, I mean just check the error message, every field of every element object in two lists are euqal.

Yes, but that doesn't mean that the objects are considered to be equal.

You need to override `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) in order for distinct objects to be considered equal. By default, the `equals` method just checks for object *identity*... in other words, `x.equals(y)` is equivalent to checking that `x` and `y` refer to the *exact same object* by default. If you want different behaviour - so that it checks for certain fields being equal - then you need to specify that behaviour in `equals()`, and implement `hashCode()` in a fashion consistent with that.

Note that this problem doesn't depend on collections at all. You'll get the same problem if you compare individual objects:

```
MySchool school1 = schoolList1.get(0);
MySchool school2 = schoolList2.get(0);
Assert.areEqual(school1, school2); // This will fail...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class must implement equals(). I will add an example implementation below:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MySchool mySchool = (MySchool) o;

    if (timestamp != mySchool.timestamp) return false;
    if (event != mySchool.event) return false;
    return !(value != null ? !value.equals(mySchool.value) : mySchool.value != null);

}
```

Then I would use hamcrest to assert on collections:

```
public void testTwoEventsAreEquals() throws Exception {
    List<MySchool> schoolList1 = Arrays.asList(new MySchool(SchoolEvent.CEREMONY), new MySchool(SchoolEvent.HOLIDAY));
    List<MySchool> schoolList2 = Arrays.asList(new MySchool(SchoolEvent.CEREMONY), new MySchool(SchoolEvent.HOLIDAY));

    assertThat(schoolList1, containsInAnyOrder(schoolList2.toArray()));
}
```

If you're using maven you must add Hamcrest as a dependency so that the above code compiles.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But then you still need to override the hashCode() also right?

Comment: @Wizard Not necessarily. Only if you use collections that use hashes, like HashMap. So if you put those MySchool objects in a HashMap then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put `equals` method as suggested by others (sorry, guys). This would be a test code in production which is not only wrong on its own, but what if you add another field to the class but forgot to update the `equals` method? Your tests won't be testing what you think they are testing. And what if `equals` method is wrong? What if it always returns true? Your tests would be always green and you would have false confidence that everything is fine. Because of course who would write a test for `equals` method.

I would strongly recommend to use a tool such as [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest). This allows you to just write `assertThat(actual, sameBeanAs(expected))` and you don't have to worry about anything. It doesn't require any changes to your production code. It will go over all fields regardless of their access modifiers. Also gives very good diagnostics. It throws `ComparisonFailure` (instead of `AssertionError`) for which IDE will show you nice side by side comparison.

The code:

```
List<MySchool> schoolList1 = generateSchools();
List<MySchool> schoolList2 = readSchoolsFromFile();

assertThat(schoolList2, sameBeanAs(schoolList2));
```

Dependency needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.shazam</groupId>
    <artifactId>shazamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Diagnostics you get:

[image: Comparison Failure diagnostics]

Note:

Remember to use `com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat`, rather than one from `hamcrest` or `junit`. It works in exactly same way as other `assertThat` methods, however if used together with `sameBeanAs`, it will throw `ComparisonFailure`, rather than `AssertionError` as others.

Comment: Who would write a test for an equals method? Everyone who actually needs an equals method, hopefully.

Comment: Yes, if you need it in production code. But would you if you needed it for test? I have never seen anyone do this and I have seen plenty such examples (i.e. tests relying on `equals` method). And note that none of the other answers says anything about it - they all say "generate it without testing".

Answer (score 0):

For two objects to be equal, their `equals()` method must return true.

The default implementation of equals() only returns true if both objects are the SAME object, but not if they are different objects with the same "content".

So, `x.equals(y);` can be `true`, even if `x == y` ("are x and y the same  object") is `false`, if the `equals()` of x method returns `true` for the parameter y.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lombok to build classes adding

`@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation before the class definition also solves this issue

example snipet

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NonNull;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Myclass {
    @NonNull
    private String var1;
    @NonNull
    private String var2;
    @NonNull
    private String var3;
    @NonNull
    private String var4;
    @NonNull
    private BigDecimal var5;
}
```